# Can't read a string of JSON

Tags: php, html, json

I have this JSON (is from Steam Market):

> {"success":true,"lowest_price":"$5.79","volume":"2,932","median_price":"$5.79"}

And I have this code:

```
    $urlm = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name='.$name;
    $market = json_decode(file_get_contents($urlm), true);
    echo $market['lowest_price'];
```

But when I try it, they give me an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: lowest_price

What is wrong? Because I have an other JSON with the same method and works perfect.

Comment: What language is your code written in?  Edit your question to add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf sorry, i'm new. All the code is in PHP.

Comment: What is the value of `$name`?

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($market)`?

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov depends, is the name of the item. Ex.: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20|%20Redline%20(Field-Tested)

Comment: @Schiem array (size=1)
  'success' => boolean true

Comment: @Shankar I try it and don't work

Comment: first do var_dump(file_get_contents($urlm)); what is the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your varaiable:

```
$urlm = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name='. urlencode($name);
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't think in that.